# extracting string using capture groups (using re.match)

Tags: python, regex, python-2.7

Here is my regular expression where I am trying to retrive 3 Capture groups

`res = re.match("^(?![()]*)([()])(.*)$", input)`

and this is my expected result

```
input = "This is a ()demo)"
I would need 3 capture groups 
res.group(1) -> "This is a "
res.group(2) -> "("
res.group(3) -> ")demo)"

input = "Another demo )(continues...()"
res.group(1) -> "Another demo "
res.group(2) -> ")"
res.group(3) -> "(continues...()"

input = "(last demo () and finally"
res.group(1) -> ""
res.group(2) -> "("
res.group(3) -> "last demo () and finally"
```

But the regex I have written do not match any of the 3 inputs I have given above. What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: @anubhava thanks for pointing it out. Corrected

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first thing you're doing wrong is using a negative lookahead assertion

```
(?![()]*)
```

I'm guessing you were trying to say "match any character *except* `()`".  You can do that with the regular matching groups by starting the group with a `^` symbol.

```
([^()]*)
```

Otherwise, your regex is pretty much correct.

Here is a regex that will give you the expected output

```
^([^()]*)([()])(.*)$
```

https://regex101.com/r/SD0L06/1